subject-verb agreement in the sentence of "there is another ten minutes of the game to go"

There’s still another ten minutes of the game to go, but for practical purposes it’s already over.

There is still another ten minutes of the game to go, but ~.
Is this sentence grammatically right?
Should I replace the above sentence with the one below?

There are still another ten minutes of the game to go, but for practical purposes it’s already over.


People say "there's"  with the plural all the time. It has become accepted.

'Ten minutes' is understood as meaning 'a ten-minute period'. Not very logical, but common in informal speech.

What @Lambie said. But it's not common to use uncontracted there is before a plural subject - only contracted There's still ten minutes to go.

Both are used in colloquial English. It is clear an alternative, "There are still ten minutes of the game to go, but for practical purposes it’s already over," is grammatically correct (without "another").
However, the question is should "another" be treated as singular or plural? Each of the following might be considered acceptable colloquial English.

There is another hour remaining.
There is an hour remaining.
There are two hours remaining.
There is another two hours remaining.

Wait! How can that last be correct? Consider that "is" refers to "another", and the "two hours" are lumped together as remaining time. Think of it as:

The remainder is two hours.

In formal writing, I'd prefer to use one of the other constructions, though.

We commonly say: There's plus plural. NOT there is plus plural.

@Lambie, that's correct.

Consider a parallel, but interrogative utterance:

How much of the game is [not are] left?

Or something like

There is six feet of thread left on the spool.

In such constructions, fragments like ten minutes and six feet express the magnitudes of quantities. And in each case, that quantity is the thing that remains. And quantity is being used as a mass (AKA non-count) concept.
